# fix clicking html link when already at destination causing repeat folder in address bar

Tags: php, html, redirect, hyperlink, href

if i am at the current address: "pages/tasks.html"
then click a link that has:
`<li><a href="./pages/tasks.html">Post Task</a></li>` 
my address becomes:
"/pages/pages/task.html"
Is there any way i can just remove the entire address bar and put the info back? that would allow me to use a header.php template for all of my pages, even if they are in different folders.

Comment: `./tasks.html` try that

Comment: that works but is not accessible from another folder that contains pages with header.php

Comment: You might find the [`<base>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) useful. Or it might just complicate things futher, depending on your context.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should do that using ".." notation (which means a folder back) so like `<li><a href="./../tasks.html">Post Task</a></li>`

Another solution would be using an absolute path instead of local. So starting from the root directory of you pages like root/pages/task.html

Comment: i was able to figure it out!
```href="../../pages/tasks.html">Post Task</a></li>```

Comment: So you solve it?
Maybe try removing pages before such as `href="./tasks.html"`

else try for a absolute path. If you need to use `source` to import the php header, then you could change the path for that